# Sprint Boot, Thymeleaf and Form Input Validation - Changing the color of the error message

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My environment is Spring Boot 1.2.7.RELEASE using Thymeleaf.

I have validation for fields working nicely, but I would like to do some formatting for the error message. I seems that whatever I put into the message on the server side gets passed to my page escaped, so I guess I have to do this in my Thymeleaf template using css.

But how? I have tried a bunch of things, like this:

```
<label for="password" title="Enter your password here">Password</label> 
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" th:field="*{password}" cssErrorClass="form-field-error" size="15"/> 
<p class="form-error-text" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">There was a problem with your password</p>
```

This causes the error text not to be rendered at all. If I remove the class="form-field-text" I get the error message to render int eh correct spot.

So I guess the bottom line is, how can I apply a css class to the validation error text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `th:errorclass="form-field-error"` instead of `cssErrorClass="form-field-error"`

http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#errcl

Comment: Thanks, that made the outline of the password field red. Can I make the text of the error message that is displayed red as well?

Comment: you need to edit css as `p.form-error-text { color: red; }`

Comment: So, this works:  p.form-error-text{color:red;font-size:13px;}  but this does not: p.form-error-text{color:#b24747;font-size:13px;}  Any idea why?